# read individual nodes from an xml url using pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read an XML file and access one specific attribute, in this case the `DonorAdvisedFundInd` attribute, and use it to create a dataframe in Pandas. So far I've tried the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import requests
 
xml_data = requests.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201903199349320465_public.xml").content
 
xtree = et.parse(xml_data)
xroot = xtree.getroot()
 
df_cols = ["DAF"]
df_rows = []
for node in xroot:
    is_DAF = node.attrib.get("DonorAdvisedFundInd")
    df_rows.append({"DAF":is_DAF})
out_df = pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns=df_cols)
out_df
```

but I'm getting this error message: `Errno  36: file name too long`

I appreciate any feedback and alternative suggestions anybody can provide. Thank you!

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I just updated the code with some new information so please take a look. I am simply trying to create a pandas dataframe that contains the value of <DonorAdvisedFundInd> from the XML file.

Comment: The value of `<DonorAdvisedFundInd>` in the XML is 0. it would help if you posted a sample of the expected output. a diagram to highlight what you are after

Comment: @sammywemmy that’s all I’m after. The 0. In this case it is one value but eventually I will be scanning hundreds of thousands of these XML files and retrieveing all the values so in some cases it’ll be 0 and some cases it is 1. From this XML file I would like to just create a dataframs with that 0 value.

Comment: This is the only row in the XML for your element : ``<DonorAdvisedFundInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</DonorAdvisedFundInd>
``

Comment: oh I see. ok. What is this for ``{"DAF":is_DAF})``.

Comment: @sammywemmy well I’m hoping that it grabs that value from the XML file and appends it to the dataframe but it doesnt seem to be working. Also please see the original post because im getting an error message about the file length.

Comment: is there any content in xml_data for you?

Comment: @sammywemmy yes, printing xml_data prints out my entire xml file with no problem. If you don't mind, can I try running the exact code you used? Also I'm using JupyterLab Notebook online if that makes a difference.

Comment: not a problem. go ahead. had no issues parsing the data; possibly do a debug to find out what line in your code is triggering the error

Comment: @sammywemmy Same error. Looks like it's being caused by the parse not the request, because xml_data does contain the entire file. Could this just be a limitation of the online platform I'm using? Does the remainder of my code look like it should work?

Comment: iterating a dataframe is not efficient, so that should go. But that is not important right now, you should try it on your local machine and see if anything changes

Comment: @sammywemmy I'm not entirely sure how to run the code on my mac terminal because it doesn't let me install pandas or requests but I tried it on IBM Cloud and got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Consider the new Pandas 1.3+ method, [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). In fact, in its [IO tools docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-xml), there is an example of retrieving an AWS S3 bucket IRS-990 XML forms, requiring the `s3fs` package. Otherwise pass URL directly without need of `requests`.

Importantly, since the IRS 990 form maintains a default namespace, use the `namespaces` argument for use in XPath query. Note: below `xpath` must be adjusted for the parent of `DisplayName` node, where `DisplayName` and its siblings migrate as columns in data frame.

**S3 Path**

```py
df = pd.read_xml(
    "s3://irs-form-990/201903199349320465_public.xml",
    xpath=".//irs:Parent_of_DisplayName",
    namespaces={"irs": "http://www.irs.gov/efile"}
)
```

**Https Path**

```py
df = pd.read_xml(
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201903199349320465_public.xml",
    xpath=".//irs:Parent_of_DisplayName",
    namespaces={"doc": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"}
)
```